# How to specify a self-referencing association table with extra data in sqlalchemy / sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering what the correct way is to store data in one table and then map relations between the records of that table in another table.

Consider the two tables `Person` and `Friends`:

```
class Person(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Person'

    id =  Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column('Name', String)

class Friends(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Friends'

    id = Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    person_a = Column('PersonA', Integer, ForeignKey('Person.Id'), primary_key=True)
    person_b = Column('PersonB', Integer, ForeignKey('Person.Id'), primary_key=True)
    status = Column('Status', String())
```

Let's assume I have the following the following records in the `Person` table:

```
person_x = Person({'name': 'Erin'})
person_y = Person({'name': 'Karen'})
person_z = Person({'name': 'Chad'})

session.add_all([person_x , person_y , person_z])
session.commit()
```

I now want to store two `Person` in `Friends` and add information about their `Status`, e.g., linking `person_y` and `person_z` in `Friends` and adding "**befriended**" to `Friends.Status`:

| Id | PersonA | PersonB | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | befriended |

I'm using a `sqlite` engine. What is the correct / best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try this? `session.add(Friends(id=0, person_a=person_x.id, person_b=person_y.id, status="befriended"))`

Comment: @GordThompson shouldn't there be any `relationship()` defined in the classes?

Comment: You can define relationships if you want them, but they are not mandatory.